# Is it possible to do device discovery on iPhone without using Bonjour?

Tags: iphone, bonjour

I want to discover a custom device that has both WiFi and Bluet that does not have a Bonjour server.  Is there any way to discover it

Comment: Whether or not you can discover it is entirely up to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. That's why Bonjour a.k.a. Zeroconf was invented. The ideal solution is to add Bonjour/Zeroconf support on the custom device.

A poor alternative: If the device gets its address via DHCP, you could use the DHCP server to help you. E.g. many DHCP servers provide a web interface in which you can look up a list of DHCP clients' names and IP addresses. Some servers and routers have an option to serve the names of DHCP clients via the DNS server.

Comment: This is not good news for my Bluetooth gadget running a tiny 8-bit microcontroller. Or is Bluetooth discovery a different story?

Comment: Zeroconf is for TCP/IP discovery, so it would only apply to your Bluetooth device if it's Bluetooth TCP/IP I guess. But being Bluetooth, there are other Bluetooth-specific ways to know the details about the device.